# Idols made by robots/machines

Tags: rambam, avodah-zarah, mishneh-torah, grama, issurei-hanaa

Maimonides says in [Avodat Kochavim, Chapter Eight](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> It is permitted to derive benefit from anything that has not been **manipulated by man or that was not made by man**, even though it was worshiped [as a deity].

Does this mean that an idol fashioned by a robot can be benefitted from, since the idol was not fashioned by a man?

Comment: My understanding was that the Rambam was contrasting this with naturally made idols (i.e. a mountain that is served as a god). I suspect a machine-made idol would lean more towards being like a man-made idol for this rule. Although there are also differences between Jewish made and non-Jewish made idols, I wonder where this case would fall for that rule.

Comment: Note that a robot has to be programmed by a human being. As a result it would be like something made by a tool and thus *man-made*.